# Invalid Qualifier VBA in IF/ELSE statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new at using VBA (just started learning it a couple weeks ago), and I am trying to create a macro that searches for a specific phrase within the sheet and then copies the numbers in that corresponding row into another sheet that creates a PO.

The sheet that is used to gather the information is ever changing because it is created for specific jobs so a search has to be done to find the correct job that needs a PO. once that is found it takes the total information and quantities from "travel hours" all the way to "freight" and then places them into the corresponding sections in the PO template.

When I test it I get an error that says "invalid qualifier" I have it commented in the code.

On top of that error, I'm sure there has to be an easier way going about doing this. I'm all about learning new things, so please feel free to edit where it is needed.

Thanks for any help in advance!

here is the code listing:

```
       Sub Extract_job_info()

Dim Title As String
Dim Param As String
Dim Message As String
Dim defaultRef As String
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim WorksheetExists As Boolean
Dim CreatePO As Integer
Dim InRowB As Long
Dim InColB As Range


Set POSheet = Sheets("Request for PO Template")




'create an input box to ask for job number to exract to a PO


'set message details
Title = "Job Number"
Message = "Please enter the job number you would like to extract information from."
defaultRef = "Enter job number here"

'input box
Param = InputBox(Message, Title, defaultRef)

'for loop to check if job exists
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Following line ignores case in comparison
    If UCase(Sht.Name) = UCase(Param) Then
        WorksheetExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next Sht
'If job does not exist
If WorksheetExists = False Then
    MsgBox ("Job number does not exist")

'if job exists
Else
   CreatePO = MsgBox("Would you like to extract job number " & Param & " to make a PO?", vbYesNo, Confirm)

    'if user does not want to create a PO
        If CreatePO = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub

    'if user wants to create a PO
    'find total travel hours

       ElseIf CreatePO = vbYes Then



        InRowB = 1 'for testing



        Set InColB = Sht.Rows(InRowB).Find(What:="Cost", _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not InColB Is Nothing Then

        POSheet.Range("F30").Value = InColB.End(xlToRight).Value

            Else
             MsgBox "'Cost' cell not found!", vbCritical
              Exit Sub
        End If

        'copy total travel hours
        'object variable or with block variable not set
        InColB.End(xlToRight).Copy

        'paste total travel hours into PO
        POSheet.Range("F30").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


        End If




End If




End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to describe exactly what you're trying to acheive here - looks like you're searching the first row for "cost", but then what are the next steps?

Comment: Two tips that will help you solve this on your own. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your modules and Use the `Debug>>Compile` tool on the toolbar. The [Excel Object Model reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194068.aspx) is also an invaluable tool.

Comment: @TimWilliams where the cost row is there are 11 columns that house information. Each section of the cost is added up by the amount. So for example, say someone traveled 2 hours to get to a site. There is a billable rate for those 2 hours. So it takes the travel hours and multiplies them by a set rate. I need to take the total cost of each of the columns that have a total cost and transfer them onto a specific cell in another worksheet. 

I think that explains it a little clearer.

Comment: When assigning a range object (or any object type) you need to use `Set` (and remove that `.Column` from the end of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: compiled but not tested

```
Sub Extract_job_info()

    Dim Title As String
    Dim Param As String
    Dim Message As String
    Dim defaultRef As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, shtJob As Worksheet
    Dim POSheet As Worksheet
    Dim CreatePO As Integer
    Dim InRowB As Long
    Dim InColB As Range

    Set POSheet = Sheets("Request for PO Template")

    'set message details
    Title = "Job Number"
    Message = "Please enter the job number you would like to extract information from."
    defaultRef = "Enter job number here"

    Param = InputBox(Message, Title, defaultRef)

    'find sheet
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If UCase(Sht.Name) = UCase(Param) Then
            Set shtJob = Sht
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Sht

    'If job does not exist
    If shtJob Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Sheet for '" & Param & "' was not found !")
    Else
        If MsgBox("Would you like to extract job number '" & _
           Param & "' to make a PO?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then

            InRowB = 1 'for testing

            Set InColB = Sht.Rows(InRowB).Find(What:="Cost", _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not InColB Is Nothing Then
                POSheet.Range("F30").Value = InColB.End(xlToRight).Value
            Else
                MsgBox "'Cost' cell not found!", vbCritical
            End If 'found "cost"

        End If 'user confirmed extract

    End If 'got sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: I made that change and I received an "object required" error??

Sorry if I am being a pain haha

Comment: My apologies 
'object required error
        Set InColB = Sht.Rows(InRowB).Find(What:="Cost", _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

Comment: Did you declare InColB as Range?  You can't use `String` (did you switch that back in your code - you had `Range` before....)

Comment: I didn't. I changed it and it is now coming up with another error in the next part of the code. I updated the code in the original post.  The error is marked with the error that pops up

Comment: That's the error my code checks for - you should include that part

Comment: I did. I'm thinking I may have done something backwards, because I am trying to locate the "cost" section where the sht variable is located. the POSheet variable is the destination with the cost is going to be,

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim InColB As String
...
InColB.End(xlToRight).Copy
```

`InColB` is a string, not a range. That operation won't work on a string

Comment: You might be kind enough to show OP how to use the column *number* to do what they're trying to do. (Yes, they're storing that number as a string.

Comment: @ray. I did that but now have come into another error. I will edit the code above and mark the new error